# Error: The value of the property 'require' is null or undefined, not a Function object in IE browser 11

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-11

I am getting below error on IE browser & our web page is not working properly.

"Error: The value of the property 'require' is null or undefined, not a Function object"

I have found below error in IE browser console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB4oT.jpg)

As per above error please fine below error code

**Error 1**

```js
require({cache:{
 'webgate/Password':function(){
  define(["dojo/_base/declare", "aps/Password", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/query"], 
   function(declare, Password, xhr, query){
```

**Error 2**

```
 require(["dijit/registry", "aps/ready!"], function(registry) {
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`require` is not defined as a `function` when the script tries to use it as a `function`. You can always make sure you do not run into this problem by checking whether it exists:

```
if (typeof require === "function") {
    //your code
}
```

but that will just make sure you do not run into the syntax error. The main problem is semantic and you need to make sure your `require` is already defined when you try to use it. Maybe you can wrap your code into a `function` and call that `function` at the `onload` of `body`.